# Getting error when upsert=true in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose for my mongodb.
I am trying to update the existing document with an array of data.

Here's my code:

```
exports.transactions = function(req,res)
{
var transactions = req.body.transactions;
transactions.forEach(function(transaction){
//  console.log("hello "+transaction);
// });
console.log(req.body.user._id);
Dwolla.update({user_id: req.body.user._id}, {$push: {"transactions": {Amount: transaction.Amount, DestinationId: transaction.DestinationId, DestinationName: transaction.DestinationName, SourceId:transaction.SourceId,SourceName:transaction.SourceName,status:transaction.Status}}},
     { upsert: true},
    function(err, model) {
       if(err) console.log(err);
       console.log("success");
    }
);
```

});
}

The error i am getting when upsert is true is:

```
oldCb(error, result ? result.result : { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 });
TypeError: object is not a function
    at Query.callback (E:\ndash-nodejs\node_modules\mongoose
)
    at E:\ndash-nodejs\node_modules\kareem\index.js:177:19
    at E:\ndash-nodejs\node_modules\kareem\index.js:109:16
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Model:

```
'use strict';

 var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema = mongoose.Schema;

 var dwollaSchema = new Schema({
    user_id:{ type: String},
    username: { type: String },
    dwolla_id: { type: String },
    transactions: [{
        Amount: String,
        DestinationId:String,
        DestinationName:String,
        SourceId:String,
        SourceName:String,
        status:String
    }],
    modified: { type: Date, default: Date.now }
 });
  module.exports = mongoose.model('Dwolla',dwollaSchema);
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating the `Dwolla` model?

Comment: by any chance, have you written any stored javascript on MongoDB?

Comment: @prasun no, I don't think so.